# How to display some message to allow SWF flash activation on Chrome broswer?

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

When I embed my SWF to my html files, chrome shows nothing, not even a message that asks for **"click here to activate flash"**

Is there a way to display a clear message so chrome shows the Autorise Flash popup ?
For now I need to do it manually: Flash->always active on website.

Comment: _"When I embed my SWF to my html files"_ Got a link to check problem in action?